# Regex to not match anything in brackets, only letters, numbers and spaces, and nothing after a dot

Tags: python, regex

For example, I have a filename `[foo] FooBar[!].bar`

How can I use regex to match `FooBar` but not `[foo]`, `[!]` or `.bar`

BTW, I'm using Python Regex, if that has any bearing.

Basically, I want to match anything that is not after a dot, or is not in brackets.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: `(?![.])(?!\.)[\w ]+` is what I've tried.
It won't match `[!]`, the brackets surrounding `[foo]` and the dot in `.bar`, but will match everything else

Comment: I think we need more sample inputs and outputs

Comment: `Spam n Eggs[u].eggs` will match everything except for the bracket characters themselves, and the dot character. My lookarounds are broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fileName = '[abc][def]Real Name[!].exe'
name = re.search('(\[[^]]*\])*([\w\s]+)', fileName).group(2)
print name
```

This should print 'Real Name'

Comment: This seems to work very well, thanks a lot, though may I inquire how this works?

@Ionut Hulub

Comment: This jumps over all the words inside brackets ( [ and ] ) and then returns what is next until a character different from a letter, digit, space or underline is found.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:^|])(?!\.)([\w\s]+)(?:\[|$)'
```

This should match any word+space combination surrounded by `]`and `[` or starting and ending the string and is not preceded by a dot.

Comment: This would fail for the folloing input: '][a]FooBar.txt'. I do understand that the OP was not specific enough, but when adding a new answer make sure it's better then the current answers, not worse.

Comment: I'm not just looking for "FooBar", I'm looking for anything that is not in a bracket, and does not follow a dot.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace it all:

```
>>> re.sub(r'\[.*?\]|\..*', '', '[foo] FooBar[!].bar')
    ' FooBar'
```

Comment: I need to be able to do more than `[foo] FooBar[!].bar`

See my other input and revised question

Comment: @ron975: Anything more specific? This chops off anything in square brackets or after a dot.

Comment: Some more examples

`Spam n Eggs[u].eggs` should only match "Spam n Eggs"
`[helloworld]ABCXYZ [3].abc`should only match "ABCXYZ"